# How can I make one Vim viewport follow another?

Tags: vim

When working in Vim I normally split the screen into two vertically. Often both of these viewports are displaying the same file. Is there a way to associate their positions in the file?

Hopefully I make one of them always show the lines immediately following the other, so that as I scroll around in either viewport the other updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature is called [scroll binding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-binding). It is controlled by the values of the [`'scrollbind'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrollbind') and [`'scrollopt'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'scrollopt') options.

Usage:

1. Adjust your scrollopt settings.
   Probably you at least want `:set scrollopt+=hor`.
2. Position each window (split) so they match up however you like.
3. `:set scrollbind` in each window.
4. Scroll around. Movement in any scroll-bound window will be reflected in all other scroll-bound windows.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.